# AngularJS: my Accordion expands, but does not collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have an accordion object in AngularJS that is data driven. Here is what my html looks like:

HTML:

```
 <div class="field-accordion" ng- if="field.fieldAccordion">
  <ul class=a ccordion>
    <li ng-repeat="fieldAccordion in field.fieldAccordion" ng- click="accordion.current = fieldAccordion.fieldName">
      {{ fieldAccordion.fieldName }}
        <ul ng-show="accordion.current == fieldAccordion.fieldName">
          <li ng-repeat="fieldSub in fieldAccordion.fieldSub">
            {{fieldSub.fieldName}}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Then in my JS file, I simply use it like this:

JS:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.mySettings({
Header: '',
Title: '',
Img: '',
fieldAccordion: [{
// "this is my accordion list"
```

This works great for me. Whenever I click on the parent, it expands. The problem that I'm having is I can't get it to collapse. I am also trying to do it while keeping everything data driven like it is now. Is there anything I can change in my HTML to allow the text to collapse after expanding ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is because of a new scope being created, what you need to know is  **`ng-if and ng-r creates a new scope`**, I checked your code and the `ng-repeat` is the root cause of the issue! hence the variable is not updating and the accordion is not toggling. Here is a simple way to update the parent controller using the `$parent`.

I have created a mockup highlighting the issue. So instead of updating `accordion.current` which will update the scope created by the `ng-if` you can just give it as `$parent.accordion.current` in the `ng-click` which will update the parent scope and the variable will be available for the `ng-show` and the accordion toggling works as expected.

Below is a working snippet, let me know if this fix solved your issue!

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.field = {
    Header: '',
    Title: '',
    Img: '',
    fieldAccordion: [{
      fieldName: "one",
      fieldSub: [{
        fieldName: "oneone"
      }]
    }, {
      fieldName: "two",
      fieldSub: [{
        fieldName: "twotwo"
      }]
    }]
  };

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="field-accordion" ng-if="field.fieldAccordion">
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li ng-repeat="fieldAccordion in field.fieldAccordion" ng-click="$parent.accordion.current = fieldAccordion.fieldName">
        {{ fieldAccordion.fieldName }}
        <ul ng-show="accordion.current == fieldAccordion.fieldName">
          <li ng-repeat="fieldSub in fieldAccordion.fieldSub">
            {{fieldSub.fieldName}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Claudiu Does this help you?